# loopbackJs How to make model relation that FK data type is string

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I've 2 example model on my db(mySql) is campaign and campaign_status. For example

T_Campaign

id : integer (PK)
name : varchar
campaign_status : varchar (FK)
T_Campaign_Status

status : varchar (PK)
In my loopback model has simple relation as

T_Campaign belongsTo T_Campaign_Status
T_Campaign_Status hasMany T_campaign
FK is T.Campaign.campaign_status and this field is string on both model

When i called the post endpoint for inserting campaign then model validation inform me validation error status 422 and campaign_status can't be blank and value: NaN.

That look like the model need campaign_status to be insert as number. So I'm looking at the example schema on Get and Post endpoint of T_Campaign and campaign_status has data type as number even if on my campaign.json that field is specific as string.

I solve this by remove all relation on both model then the campaign_status field work properly as string but without relation some endpoint has gone and I need to use that.

So the question is what happen and how I can make my relation work with PK-FK as string not a number.

Comment: Please give some code like model json files